# JSON message recieved from KAfka using structured streaming need to be converted to a Dataset

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am recieving json from Kafka using structured streaming. Now I need to convert it to dataset so I can parse it and load in DB.
My JSON is very complex and not of fixed so can not define schema manually.

I am trying to use `sc.parallize` function to get javaRDD and then SQLContext to read RDD as json. 
But when code reach to this line it says "TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 2.0 with 1 tasks" and it never gets completed.

HEre is my scala code for structured streaming:

```
val ev = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<broker url>")
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
.option("enable.auto.commit", "true")
.option("subscribe", "<topic name>")

.load()
.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as value")
.withColumn("message", $"value".cast(StringType))
.drop("value")
.coalesce(1)
.writeStream
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1L)).outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {

  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    true
  }

  override def process(value: Row): Unit = {
    System.out.println("========================RRRRRRRRR" + value.get(0))
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .getOrCreate()

    JSONUtil.getDF(value.get(0).toString, spark.sparkContext)
    println("END");
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
}).start()
.awaitTermination()
```

From `ForeachWriter` I am calling this Java function:

```
public static void getDF(String json,SparkContext sc){

    System.out.println("GETDF");
    List<String> jsonList = new ArrayList<>();
    jsonList.add(json);
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    JavaRDD<String> javaRdd = javaSparkContext.parallelize(jsonList);
    Dataset<Row> data = sqlContext.read().json(javaRdd);
    data.show();
    data.writeStream().outputMode("update").format("console").start();
    System.out.println("GETDF END"+data.toString());
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to `writeStream` of the dataframe from `sqlContext.read().json(javaRdd)`. Can you show the code that uses `getDF`?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski i have added code in my post that calls getDF. Please check.